Scott Aikin's "modest, but not self-effacing" transcendental argument
This question is about Scott F. Aikin's 2017 paper "Modest (but not Self-Effacing) Transcendental Arguments".
The full paper is accessible here with a free account, and some ideas regarding that approach can also be found here.
The central move is to show that "Transcendental Pessimism" (= we have no knowledge or have no reliable means to assess knowledge) is self-defeating, since it is "epistemically worst" because even if it were true, there wouldn't be any evidence for it.
But is that even right? I guess, there might be possible evidence, why not? Such evidence would be a mistake on the deceiver's part, of course. But, e.g. Neo also wakes up from the Matrix and acquires evidence that the experienced world was just a very elaborate deception.
So with that in mind, how is Aikin's approach in the end any different from just employing Occam's razor?

Transcendental pessimism is not about deception, it is about knowledge of the transcendent. There can be no evidence that such knowledge is impossible by definition of the "transcendent" as beyond any possible experience. Neither Neo's "experienced" world nor the "real" one are transcendent (noumenal), they are both within his possible experience (phenomenal). So his case is moot.

@Conifold what is the meaning of "real things" then? Matrix-style skeptical hypotheses are intelligible. Doesn't the transcendental pessimist exploit this? He borrows meaningfulness from a story about experience and applies it to concepts that are fundamentally beyond experience. While the "other minds" issue also fundamentally goes beyond experience, it is directly apprehensible ... because we can count. The supposed way from the Matrix / Cartesian demon to the meaning of transcendental "real things" was a trick, and another way doesn't seem to exist.

Here’s my first attempt at absorbing the article:

There have been arguments throughout the history of philosophy for deep uncertainty about even basic judgments or beliefs (Hume, Foucault, Wittgenstein, Nietzsche, postmodernists, and others). Aiken calls some of those “epistemologically pessimistic arguments” (because they try to go ‘all the way’) transcendental; they conclude with a total epistemic judgment, something like, “all truth is inherently unknowable”.
But there have been arguments throughout the history of philosophy (including I think Parmenides, Moore, Searle, Kant, and others), that various forms of skepticism are self-defeating - for the obvious reason that those arguments, in applying to ‘everything’, also apply to themselves: if all truth is ‘relative’, then the truth ‘all truth is relative’ is relative, hence, there may be contexts in which all truth is not relative, which immediately refutes the central thesis. The problem with self-referential sentences is a frequent one in logic, and has been worked on by people like Gödel, Kripke and many others. (I like to call such statements “unstable”, since they may endlessly refute themselves in a loop; whereas we may find that their converse is stable: self-consistent; self-justifying.) Aiken says, “Transcendental arguments are attempts at making [an inarticulate] hunch explicit.”
Aiken adds a new claim to the mix: the problem with refutations to ‘transcendental pessimism’ is that ‘pessimists’ won’t accept them. He delineates two more developed, generalized critiques against transcendental pessimism: his dialectical argument, and his formal argument. He also highlights the distinction between merely arguing that “we would need belief in core epistemic ‘abilities’ to say anything about the world”, vs. proving that such epistemic judgments actually are true. He calls the former standpoint of the two “self-effacing”, since in a way it attempts to refute transcendental pessimism, but is not fully capable of bringing that all the way to an affirmation of the converse, transcendental optimism, which holds that things like knowledge, reason, truth, and even moral judgment are as real, definite, and certain as can be. Aiken says that transcendental pessimists can reject transcendental optimism because they claim that optimists’ arguments require contingent assumptions; and for the skeptic, anything that is not absolutely necessary, has no justification, and therefore its certainty must be rejected.
Aiken claims that therefore, a critique of transcendental pessimism that even the pessimist would agree to is one that is necessarily necessary: it must be something that is true ineluctably, in some way. Aiken argues that both transcendental pessimism and transcendental optimism think they can undercut the other; yet both can be abstracted into the category of ‘transcendental arguments’: no matter what they aim to prove, any transcendental argument, according to Aiken, shares two “weak points” in how it may be refuted. He names the two “problems of transcendental arguments” as being that they “beg the question”, and that they are “otiose”. “Begging the question” is roughly assuming what you want to believe in order to speciously prove a conclusion that depends on the assumed premise. It doesn’t fix the problem, just defers it. “Otiose” means “impotent”: that you cannot convince someone who already rejects a certain view of the validity of your argument, because your argument depends on its own conclusions to justify its own method of reasoning.
He concludes with a strategy he calls a forced move, where you basically evade those problems of transcendental arguments, and can succeed in convincing someone of something, even in accordance with their own premises and preferred methodology of reasoning.

I hope this gives you a general outline with which to read the paper.


I guess, there might be possible evidence, why not?

Even if the deceiver leaked some evidence, by that assumption we'd still be unable to recognize it as such.  Indeed, the point of "Transcendental Pessimism" is not even that we might be deceived, the point, simply put, is that we have no means to know either way: whence any alleged knowledge is only self-deceit.

e.g. Neo also wakes up from the Matrix

Neo had been deceived, but Neo's ability to think and judge coherently per se was never in question...

I think the most direct way to understand Aikin's point is to see that any transcendental position must ascribe a state to the universe, i.e. it has to say that the universe 'is such as I am describing it'. With transcendental optimists this isn't a problem: a transcendental optimist might be wrong, but position is not inherently self-defeating. But transcendental pessimists are ultimately caught in a bind where they assert the universe has the state of not having a state: the universe 'is such that it lacks any such-ness.' It seems to be impossible to make a negational transcendental (universal) claim without simultaneously asserting or implying a postural (universal) transcendental claim.
Concretely, a transcendental skeptic would have to say something like: "the universe is such that we can never know the such-ness of it", which is self-evidently paradoxical.
Though Aikin himself doesn't go down the following rabbit hole, it strikes me that this is similar to Russell's Paradox and the Liar's Paradox: what I think of as the problem of negational self-reference. Whenever something points back to itself with a negation (e.g., the set of all sets that do not contain themselves; the truth value of a statement from someone who lies…), it seemingly cannot resolve into 'this answer' or 'that answer', much the way a Möbius strip can't be resolved into 'this side' or 'that side'. If we follow one we end up at the other, less like an infinite regress than like a dog chasing its own tail. My instinct says it's a problem of language, but I can't quite get my fingers on it. C'est la vie…!


The central move is to show that "Transcendental Pessimism" (= we have
no knowledge or have no reliable means to assess knowledge) is
self-defeating, since it is "epistemically worst" because even if it
were true, there wouldn't be any evidence for it.
But is that even right?

Yes, essentially.

I guess, there might be possible evidence,
why not? Sch evidence would be a mistake on the deceiver's part, of
course.

There is no requirement for any deceiver or active deception here.  In fact, the opposite: in order to be deceived, we need to accept something to be true that is in fact false, but transcendental pessimism says there is no basis for us to accept anything to be true in the first place.
Evidence for a premise is a fact or pattern of facts that we accept as true and that tends to support the truth of the premise.  But in addition to denying any basis to accept any facts as true, transcendental pessimism says that if we did have any true facts then there would be no valid way to draw any conclusions from them. That would be a means to assess knowledge.
Transcendental pessimism is epistemically worst because it is a philosophical black hole.  We cannot reason about it without assuming it false, because if it were true then there would be no valid way to reason about anything (and look at me assuming it false in order to make that argument).  In particular, we could not reason about transcendental pessimism itself, which I take to be Aiken's point.
This does not prove transcendental pessimism false.  I nevertheless reject it, because I enjoy thinking.
